# Translation from Java to Oracle SQL: use every element into a loop as result of a SELECT statement

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

It's my first time using Oracle function.
I'm trying to translate this piece of code in Java to Oracle SQL.

```
 It's present a SELECT statement before the loop
        for (int i = 0; i < checkList.size(); i++) {
                        
                      String check= checkList.get(i);
        }
```

My translation:

```
CURSOR C1 IS 
 ... select statement ... 
BEGIN
    FOR vItems IN C1.COUNT LOOP 
    -- I don't know how to continue, taking the first value of the select 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: There's insufficient information to even attempt a translation. In the Java code, the variable `first` is used, but there's no mention of what value it might contain. Similarly, there is a `flag.set` and a `flags.set`. What is/are `flag`/`flags`, what does the `set` method do, etc? `String priority` is given a value but doesn't appear to be otherwise used. And the SELECT statement which is supposedly driving this logic isn't shown, making it impossible to understand what's going on.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica but if I want the result of a query to be evaluated one by one, how could do?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica it's important the first part. How to get evaluate the value from a select statement into the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to do something for each `EMPNO` in a table, `EMP`, in schema `SCOTT`. (Almost every Oracle database installation has a standard schema, `SCOTT`; one of the tables is `EMP`, with primary key `EMPNO`. This is often used for testing and illustrations.)

To do something with each value of `EMPNO` in a loop, in PL/SQL, you would do something like this:

```
declare
  cursor c1 is select empno from scott.emp;
begin
  for rec in c1 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.empno);  -- or more generally, "DO SOMETHING"
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Note that there is no "array index" here - you reference "records" directly. (By the way, if you want the rows to be processed in some specific order, you include that in an `order by` clause directly in the `select` statement!)

Although you can write this much more compactly (no equivalent in Java, I think):

```
begin
  for rec in (select empno from scott.emp) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.empno);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: can ensure rec.empno into a variable? Could I use directly rec.empno for a switch statement? Thank you

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError - What happened when you tried?